# Rotating a small crank with a large wheel

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I wonder if there's a way to rotate a small crank by turning a large wheel. Here's a diagram:

[image]

Is there a way to design the slot on the wheel for the crank pin? A standard, straight radial slot won't do since the diameter of the small wheel is less than the radius of the big wheel. Is there some some mechanism for achieving this?

Comment: internal gear ring?  It isn't clear how much manufacturing is allowed here.

Comment: With all of the hidden lines, it is hard to tell what you are looking for. Are you wanting to use gears or are you wanting to move the smaller wheel just with a slot?

Comment: Planetary gearing?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was hoping to turn the crank with just a slot.